# Getting Number of connections currently viewing mvc3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

MVC3 vb.net Application using built in session management. I have an mvc3 application that I would like to add being able to see the current number of users online to whether they are logged in or not. I have tried using:

```
   Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline.ToString
```

But that only keeps track of current users logged in which is not acceptable in what I am trying to do. Is there any other method that keeps track of connections????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook on the `Session_Start` and `Session_End` events in global.asax. Increase a counter in Session_Start and decrease it in Session_End.

Or you can read this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/05/reading-all-users-session.aspx) on how to read all users session state via a dirty reflection hack. So you don't have to count yourself.